# How to add jar files for Hue in Cloudera?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hue

I'm running an SQL query on a JSON serde table. It's working in the Hive CLI, but it's failing in Hue with the error:

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

I guess it's due to the missing jar file; any idea how to add the jar file `hive-hcatalog-core-1.2.1.jar` for Hue?

Comment: the command "ADD JAR <hdfs path/jar name>" only works in hive CLI, but not in hue? any idea how to load jar in HUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run **ADD JAR hive-hcatalog-core-1.2.1.jar** in hue before your query this thing will be present till your current secession persists.

Comment: the problem was the user didn't have permission to the directory where i placed the file, that's why it was failing in HUE, to be specific                  "ADD JAR <local file path>/jarname"

Answer (score 3):

Place your jar in HDFS and add same path by using `ADD JAR hdfs:///user/hive/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-1.2.1.jar ;`

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, I tried it before posting, but its only working in HIVE CLI in unix, but not in HUE, any specific way to load jar in hue

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others, who might face same issue either for this particular jar "hive-hcatalog-core-1.2.1.jar" or any udf jar:

In the HUE - Query Editor, run the following command:

```
add jar hdfs:/hive-hcatalog-core-1.2.1.jar;
```

Please note single quotes is not required as is the case with Hive CLI

Answer (score -1):

Exact command cloudera gave is ADD JAR {{lib_dir}}/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar;

> 1)I am unable to find hive/lib directory on CDH 5

The {{lib_dir}} on CDH installed environments for Hive would either be /usr/lib/hive/ or /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/ (depending on packages or parcels being in use).

this is the way to add jar in cloudera

## for this you have to change to supper user by use this command

```
      SUDO SU
```

it will change to supper user